# Return Multiple things in a map function - react/Javscript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

What would be the most efficient way to return multiple things in a .map function. For example, 2 **separate** console.log statements?

For example: This works just fine:

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
      {mycataobjects.map((myobject) => console.log(myobject.name))}
    </div>
  );
```

However, how would I add another console.log to this map, so that for each object in the array I get the phrase "Hello"

I tried the below but it does not work. It only prints "Hello" once. I want it printed for every object in the my.object array. What would be the best way to do this?

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
      {mycataobjects.map(
        (myobject) => console.log(myobject.name),
        console.log("Hello")
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Why are you using console.log at all `map` doesn't return anything in this case so it's relatively pointless.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really interested in the return values you could return a tuple kind of type and then flatten the array:

```js
const arr = mycataobjects.map(item => [1, 2]);
const values = arr.flat();
```

However in your example if you just want to call `console.log` twice you'd need to add braces to your arrow function body:

```js
mycataobjects.map(
  (myobject) => {
    console.log(myobject.name);
    console.log("Hello");
  }
);
```

Note that `console.log` is a void function so would just return `undefined`. Trying to grab its return value is not all that useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Because you pass a callback that will return immediately after being invoked.
You should change it to

```
(myobject) => {
  console.log(myobject.name);
  console.log("Hello");
}
```